# Printer driver conflicts

Tags: printing

On a Dell portable running XP Pro.

We've got a HP 7590 all-in-one inkjet printer in the office (over a wireless network, TCP/IP connection) and a 1300 all-in-one inkjet printer at home (attached by USB cable). Unfortunately there is a driver conflict between the two and it is 'impossible' to have them work on the same machine (Hewlett Packard have admitted this, and no, they're not going to do anything about it).

I was thinking, if I set up two user accounts in XP: 'office' and 'home', does anyone know if it is possible to install a separate printer SOLELY for each account. If it's possible, that would hopefully solve the driver conflict as the two drivers would never be loaded at the same time.

Thanks in advance for any help, I've been struggling with this for some days, and HP support are far from helpful!!

Answer (score 2):

No, drivers are installed for a whole Windows installation, not a single account.
The only way around is to virtualize the printer drivers with something like Symantec's virtualization.
Or have a second XP install...

Comment: Many thanks to both, this is what I thought. Two XP installations seems a bit excessive, I'll check out Symantec's virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help. Even if you set up different printers on separate accounts both drivers will need to be installed, leading to conflicts.